# Ansible. Ошибка проверки доступности хостов в файле инвентаризации

Tags: linux, ssh, ansible

Выполнил настройку сервера и клиента ansible.
Заполнил файл hosts2.ini в виде:

```
[local]
ip-adress_1
ip-adress_2
```

Создал ключ SSH, добавлен ключ на сервере:

```
# ssh-copy-id пользователя@ip-adress_1
# ssh-copy-id пользователя@ip-adress_2
```

Проверил доступность всех хостов в файле инвентаризации:

```
#  ansible all -m shell -a "whoami" -i /home/user/playbooks/hosts2.ini -b -K
ip-adress_1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >> root
ip-adress_2 | CHANGED | rc=0 >> root
```

Первый раз всё хорошо, но после переподключения и проверке ошибка:

```
ip-adress_1 | UNREACHABLE! => { "changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: user@ip-adress_1: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).", "unreachable": true }
ip-adress_2 | UNREACHABLE! => { "changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: user@ip-adress_2: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).", "unreachable": true }
```

Помогите разобраться с проблемой.

Comment: См. [Failed to connect to the host...permission denied (publickey, password) unreachable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71694179/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась.
Была не верная команда генерации ключа.

Было: `# ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f ~/.ssh/manager`
Стало: `# ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096`

Было: `# ssh-copy-id пользователь@ip-adress_1`
Стало: `# ssh-copy-id -i /.ssh/id_rsa.pub пользователь@ip-adress_1`

Comment: ssh-keygen для генерации ключа